# Tkinter entry widget - typed values gets copied to other entries

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I am trying to create multiple Entry widgets on different pages of a notebook widget. However, when  I type something in one Entry, it gets automatically copied to corresponding Entry on all pages. Please help. Here is my code.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *

app = Tk()
nb = ttk.Notebook(app)

pages = []
canvas_left = []
canvas_right = []
entry_labels = []
entry_values = []

for i in range(3):
    pages.append(ttk.Frame(nb))
    canvas_left.append(tk.Canvas(pages[i], width=500, height=400, bd=0, highlightthickness=0))
    canvas_left[i].pack(side=LEFT)
    entry_values.append([])
    for j in range(8):
            entry_values[i].append(Entry(app, width=20, text="Window "+str(j+1), fg="white", bg="gray", font=("Helvetica", 12)))
            canvas_left[i].create_window(125, 20 + j*35, anchor="w", window=entry_values[i][j])
    nb.add(pages[i], text="Display "+(i+1).__str__())
nb.pack(side=TOP)
app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `text` option of `Entry` widget is the same as `textvariable` option. So you use same variable name across the frames and they will be updated at the same time when one of them is updated.

Remove the `text` option from those `Entry(...)`.

Comment: do you have an example to handle this case?